# Singleton vs class variable. What is the difference and what to choose?

Tags: ruby, singleton

I want to add configuration to my module. I saw that some projects ([geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/configuration.rb) for example) use Singleton class for this purpose. I noticed that writing configuration into a class variable will have the same effect

Are there any differences?
Will be class variable a safe solution in the multithread app?

See the code example below:

```
# using class variable

module MyApp
  class << self
    attr_accessor :config

    def configure(config)
      self.config = config
    end
  end
end

# using Singleton

module M
  def self.config
    Configuration.instance.data
  end

  def self.configure(config)
    Configuration.instance.data = config
  end

  class Configuration
    include Singleton

    attr_accessor :data

    # other methods
  end
end

# or use class variable in the Configuration class itself
# in case if we need additional methods for configuration

module M
  def self.config
    Configuration.data
  end

  def self.configure(config)
    Configuration.data = config
  end

  class Configuration
    class << self    
      attr_accessor :data
    end

    # other methods

  end
end
```

Comment: What is `Singleton` in `include Singleton`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland [Singleton](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) is a ruby core class that implements [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)